# Getting Started with Rails official Tutorial, ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I have followed the tutorial letter for letter and I am still getting a forbidden attributes error. I have rails 4.1.4 and ruby 2.1.2.  here are my controller methods for a new article

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else  
      render 'new'
    end
end
private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

I'm sure it's just one singular/plural thing I mistyped or something stupid, but I've been at this one stupid error for more than hour now, so any help is appreciated

Comment: Up in the first line, you need to change `params[:article]` to `article_params`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I need to let them know so they can fix that in the tutorial. Make this an answer and I'll mark it as so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up in the first line, you need to change `params[:article]` to `article_params`.

Rails 4+ refuses to initialize an Active Model object unless the attributes passed to it have been explicitly whitelisted. This is a Rails security feature known as [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) that was introduced to better protect against [mass assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability) — "a computer vulnerability where an active record pattern in web application is abused to modify data items that the user should be not normally allowed to access".

`params[:article]` is an unsanitized hash passed to the `create` action via a POST request to `/articles`. It could contain data that sets attributes of the `Article` model in unintended and unexpected ways. Rails 4+ does you a favor by throwing an exception and not allowing such code to run, rather than leave the onus of security solely on you.

`article_params` is a call to the `private` method listed in your example `ArticlesController`. Notice that it explicitly requires an `:article` parameter and only permits `:title` and `:text` attributes. This prevents a malicious user from authoring a particularly offensive article and then, say, posting it under an innocent individual's name by passing that person's `:user_id` along with the offensive article.

For a real world example of a mass assignment exploit in Rails, here's an Errata Security [article](http://blog.erratasec.com/2012/03/rubygithub-hack-translated.html#.VB-g_EuPKlI) summarizing the Github hack of 2012.